# What does from = mean inside a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following call:

```
 $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "datetime-uk-pre": function (a) {
            from = a.split(' ');
            var ukDatea = from[0].split('/');
            var ukTimea = from[1].split(':');
            return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0] + ukTimea[1] + ukTimea[0]) * 1;
        }
```

Can someone explain what the "from =" is doing here. I note that when I run 
JSHint then it tells me 'from' is not defined.

Comment: try var from = a.split(' ');?

Comment: So you randomly put `var` in front of other variables?

Comment: @zerkms not randomly, just to make them defined.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: I asked op, to clarify why they have 2 variables with `var` and one without.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think OP has written this code.

Comment: looks to me like "from" is just a variable. Where is "a" coming from? Can you post some code where it shows "a" being used?

Comment: I think you've read so much linq

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone explain what the "from =" is doing here.

It is assigning a value to a variable called `from`

> I note that when I run JSHint then it tells me 'from' is not defined.

It looks like it should be `var from =`. (Either that or `from` is intended to be used in a wider scope, but it doesn't look like a useful variable to have in a wider scope and if that was the case, there should still be a `var from;` higher up the scope chain).

Without the `var` you create a global variable.

Comment: "Without the var you create a global variable" < not necessarily global. We are not sure about the context here. The `from` variable could be defined in a closure. If not defined anywhere, then yes, it becomes global.

Comment: @Oleg — If it was, then there would be a `var from` higher up the scope chain, which was covered in the answer.

Comment: I don't think the OP has provided the entire code. So it remains a viable assumption.

Comment: @Oleg — Either there is no `var from`, in which case it is a global, or there is a `var from` higher up the scope chain. Both cases are discussed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

look's like it's just a variable here

```
from = a.split(' ');
```

Which can be accessed outside the current function scope , which is an array..

Answer (score 0):

It's just a variable. `from` doesn't mean anything special in JavaScript. It's probably being declared with `var from` somewhere, if they've used proper coding practices. Try searching for that string.

If JSHint is complaining about it, it may not have been properly declared. You might want to rewrite that line as `var from = a.split(' ');` for best practice.

Comment: I think you're too optimistic with "it's probably declared somewhere"

Comment: I have the good fortune to work with well-written code lately. Feels pretty nice. To be fair, I did qualify that with `if they've used proper coding practices.`

Answer (score 0):

`from` is just the name of a variable, just like `ukDatea` and `ukTimea` in the code above. In JavaScript if you use a new variable name without using the keyword `var` before it, the variable becomes global, which is what JSHint is trying to tell you when it says that `from` is not defined.

It should either be defined somewhere else in the code (like `var from`) or you need to add the `var` keyword before it right here, which will make the line look like this:

```
var from = a.split(' ');
```